# Getting missing Form label for mat-list-option for angular material 15 after MDC migration

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

After angular material upgrade to version 15 and MDC upgrade we are getting an accessibility error from the WAVE tool. We are getting missing-form-label error for every checkbox for the  mat-list-option.
I have tried adding aria-label ,alt-text, title and even tried adding mat-label inside the <mat-list-option>/</mat-list-option>, nothing has been worked till yet. Can someone please help me with that.

code snippet:

```
 <mat-selection-list (change)="onChange($event)" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)"
  role="listbox" #list [tabindex]="tabindex" [attr.aria-label]="getAriaLabel()">
  <mat-label hidden aria-hidden="true">MockLabel</mat-label>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let option of to.options" value="{{option['value']}}" [selected]="option.selected" 
    checkboxPosition="before" role="option" disabled="{{option['disabled']==true}}" [attr.aria-label]="option['value']"
     title="option['value']" alt-text="option['value']">
    {{option['value']}}
    <mat-label hidden aria-hidden="true">MockLabel</mat-label>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Material angular create the inputs "on-fly" so you can not add attributes to this elements created.

Well, you can use a directive that look for inside the html element mat-option and add attributes.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[accessibility]',
  standalone: true,
  exportAs: 'AttribAccess'
})
export class AttribAccessDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('accessibility') attributes!:any
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    //get the element neccesary
    const element=(this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input') ||[null])[0]
    if (element)
    {
      Object.keys(this.attributes).forEach(x=>{
        element.setAttribute(x,this.attributes[x])
      })
      
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the directive

```
 <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" 
    [accessibility]="{'aria-label':'shoe '+shoe,'aria-text':'shoe '+shoe}">
    <span >{{shoe}}</span>
 </mat-list-option>
```

NOTE That I get the element using javascript getEmlementsByTagName, you can "reach" any element if have a class with getElementsByClassName

The construction

```
const element=(this.el.nativeElement.get....() || [null])[0]
```

makes that elements becomes the first element javascript funcitn find or null

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kv7lvw?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo thanks a lot for the solution it worked for me, but  is there some way we can  do this without any DOM manipulation.

Comment: @ShwetaNikam, I'm afraid not (at least I don't know how do it). You can [add an issue] (https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/issues) and wait if the material-angular guys can solve it in the next version